# How to check the textfield is empty and then call javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I  want to view the jquery/javascript dialog box when a perticular textbox is empty..I tried below code but doesnt work..how do I add if() function to below code?

```
      <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#search_btn').click(function () {

        if ($('#form1.legacy_code_text.value') == "") { /// THIS DOESNT WORK I WANT THE CORRECT WAY FOR THIS LINE
            $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");

            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 140,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Ok": function () {

                        $('#form1').submit();



                        //*****************************************************************
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }


            });
        }
    });
});
        </script>
```

Comment: You should accept some answers to your previous questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( $('#legacy_code_text').val() == "" )
```

Comment: <input type="text" name="legacy_code_text" id="legacy_code_text" class="textfield"/></td>

Comment: sure it does :) you're welcome! don't forget to accept useful answers (previous as well) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( empty(#form1.legacy_code_text.value') )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i have done bins for above problems. So, Try on http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpat

To Run Following Script Follow steps:

1) Include latest jquery.js and jquery UI javascript file.

2) Include JQuery UI CSS file.

3) HTML:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="My Dialogue">
  <form id="form1" method="post">
    <div style="padding:10px;">
      Enter Text:
      <input type="text" name="legacy_code_text" id="legacy_code_text" class="textfield"/>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

4) jQuery:

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Ok": function() {
            var txtarea_val = $('#form1  #legacy_code_text').val();
            if (txtarea_val != '') $('#form1').submit();
            else {
                /*show your error*/
                alert("Enter Some text..!");
                return false;
            }

        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```